# How to use ExcelReader to import data into a database

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to get my program to read a .csv file and then make a database name based on an entered value, and in that databse it should create a table with entered text, from there it should take each header in the excel file and make it a column in the newly created table. Can someone help me understand how i can go about doing this? mostly the last part about reading and creating the columns please. The following is the code i have so far, it might not be complete or make sense in most part but keep in mind i am very new to this.

```
public void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string DataTableName;
    string DataBaseName;
    string ImportPath;

    DataTableName = TxtMappingArea.Text;
    DataBaseName = TxtDistributionCenter.Text;
    ImportPath = TxtCSVFileName.Text;


    String str;
    SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Integrated security=true; database=master");

    str = "CREATE DATABASE " + DataBaseName + " ON PRIMARY " +
        "(NAME = " + DataBaseName + ", " +
        "FILENAME = 'D:\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\" + DataBaseName + ".mdf'" + ", " +
        "SIZE = 2MB, MAXSIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) " +
        "LOG ON (NAME = " + DataBaseName + "_Log, " +
        "FILENAME = 'D:\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\" + DataBaseName + ".ldf', " +
        "SIZE = 1MB, " +
        "MAXSIZE = 5MB, " +
        "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";

    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
    try
    {
        myConn.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            myConn.Close();
        }
    }

    using (var stream = File.Open(ImportPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateCsvReader(stream))
        {
            var result = reader.AsDataSet();
        }
    }

    String str2;


    ////This is where I am stuck in my code:

    //str2 = "CREATE TABLE " + DataTableName + 

    SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(str2, myConn);
    try
    {
        myConn.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            myConn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for formatting, i am not accustomed to this

Comment: What are you stuck on? The syntax for `CREATE TABLE`? How to determine the column names and data types?

Comment: @D Stanley I'm stuck on the logic of how it is going to read those column names in the excel and then through code, add those names as columns to the table. I'm stuck on the logic of how it will work and what code to use to get this end result. (As i said, i am pretty new to this.)